# Which Application Insights custom api method is best for tracking client version

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have we mobile backend with Application Insights. When using the Application Insights API I can track custom data with the following methods

> TrackPageView - Pages, screens, blades or forms
>   TrackEvent - User actions and other events. Used to track user behavior or to monitor performance.
>   TrackMetric - Performance measurements such as queue lengths not related to specific events
>   TrackException - Log exceptions for diagnosis. Trace where they occur in relation to other events and examine stack traces.
>   TrackRequest - Log the frequency and duration of server requests for performance analysis.
>   TrackTrace - Diagnostic log messages. You can also capture 3rd-party logs.
>   TrackDependency - Log the duration and frequency of calls to external components on which your app depends.

Which would be most appropriate to log the version of the mobile device using the backend?

Or should I use properties, like this?

```
var client = new TelemetryClient();
client.InstrumentationKey =     client.Context.Properties.Add("ApiClientVersion", versionNumber);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to add that information to every tracking request that AI sends.
For this you need a TelemetryInitializer.

There's a sample [here](http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/%20here).

In short: You need to create an implementation of `ITelemetryInitializer` which adds your custom information to the telemetry context, and then you need to add your telemetry initializer to the `TelemetryConfiguration` instance.

```cs
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(
    new YourCustomInformationTelemetryInitializer());
```

In `YourCustomInformationTelemetryInitializer` you add the information in the `Initialize` method like this:

```cs
public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
{
    telemetry.Context.Properties["AppVersion"] = "1.2.3";
    telemetry.Context.Properties["OtherSpecialInfo"] = "whatever";
}
```

Whatever you add to the telemetry context properties will be visible in the Azure portal.

Comment: Is TelemetryInitalizer really made for setting request-specific data? In my case, the AppVersion is not the version of the web site but the version of the Android app doing the current request. And different users could have different versions of the android client.

Comment: Yes, that is what it is for. The same way that browser user-agents are added to each request if you add appinsights to a web site.